# How to set Default value in Datepicker of AEM Granite UI

Tags: datepicker, aem

background: i wanna set a default value in Datepicker of AEM Granite UI, according to [datepicker doc](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/datepicker/index.html) and [question here](https://nation.marketo.com/t5/product-discussions/set-default-value-for-date-picker-on-form-2-0/td-p/79857), now i can set the default value as today via property: value="today".

Questions:

1. how can i set it as three days after today? or two hours after current time.
2. i read the source code of datepicker, and seems it use "getExpressionHelper" function of "com.adobe.granite.ui.components.ComponentHelper" to handle the inital value of "value" property. and from this [doc](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/ui/components/ExpressionHelper.html#getString-java.lang.String-) , i can't see more detail about how to handle the inital value of "value" property. anyone can tell me or throw me a document about the detail inside? just wanna know what else option(except "today") it provided or how i can use this "value" property correctly.